# While Loop in VBA Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have delete and append functions that build Table1 based on inputs from the user. Therefore Table1 has a different number of records appending to it for every user.

My SQL code works to find the dates, but it only does it once, I need to loop the SQL code for the length of the table. I'm not great at coding, I tried a while statement, not sure if I can use variable Z in the criteria for that, but I want it to run until the due_date in the record with the smallest ID value has been filled.

Here's what I tried:

```vb
Private Sub Command7_Click()
Y = DMax("ID", "Table1", BuildCriteria("Due_date", dbDate, "Null"))
A = DMin("ID", "Table1", BuildCriteria("Due_date", dbDate, "Not Null"))
X = DMin("ID", "Table1")
Z = DLookup("Due_date", "Table1", BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(X)))

B = DLookup("Duration", "Table1", BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(Y)))
C = DLookup("Due_date", "Table1", BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(A)))
E = DateAdd("d", -B, C)

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "UPDATE Table1 " & _
    "SET " & BuildCriteria("Due_date", dbDate, CStr(E)) & " " & _
    "WHERE " & BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(Y))


While Z Is Null
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End While

End Sub
```

To illustrate:

- Before Running SQL

  [image: Before Running SQL]
- After running SQL once

  [image: After running SQL once]
- After clicking several times

  [image: After clicking several times]

The goal would be to click once and the whole table fills

Comment: Please show a sample of current data and desired results. Also, we need to see `BuildCriteria`. Altogether, this helps set up a [MCVE].

Comment: I don't really understand what BuildCriteria does, but that is my entire code pasted above, there's nothing else to really show.

Comment: My Table1 has a variable number of rows, that's why there are variable to identify the last row, the row previous to it, and then it subtracts the duration of the previous row from the last row and pastes it in the previous row. However, one button click only does this once, and I need it to do it for every record in the table without clicking the button 20+ times to complete it.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53045941/edit) your post and show original data (few rows) and what your desired output (few rows). It is hard to see what you mean in words. Interesting, in all my years, I have never heard or used MS Access' [`BuildCriteria()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.buildcriteria) method. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: Edited - Thanks!

Comment: @cm2115, I've updated my answer based on the additional information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `Z` contains the *result* returned by the `DLookup` function when evaluated as the fourth line of the definition of your sub `Command7_Click`; the value of this variable will not change unless the variable is redefined.

*The intent of your code is somewhat obscured by the use of your `BuildCriteria` function, so it is difficult to advise the best way to write the code...*

*Edit*: [BuildCriteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.BuildCriteria) is a new one for me - thanks to @Andre for pointing this out.

Since the content of your SQL statement is static, there should be no need for a loop, as nothing is changing within the loop - the SQL statement will update all records which meet your criteria and will do nothing for every subsequent iteration (unless, that is, the value to which you are updating the records also fulfils the selection criteria).

---

**EDIT**

Based on your additional explanations & screenshots, you could approach the task by iterating over a recordset sorted by your `ID` field and successively calculating the appropriate `Due_date` for each record - something like:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dat As Date
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from Table1 order by ID desc")
    With rst
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do Until .EOF
                If Not IsNull(!Due_date) Then
                    dat = !Due_date
                Else
                    dat = DateAdd("d", -!Duration, dat)
                    .Edit
                    !Due_date = dat
                    .Update
                End If
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Though based on your screenshots, it seems that you are trying to use Access like an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: The SQL statement only updates the second to last record. The table has an ID field, Task field, duration field, and due_date field. When it's first created the due date is appended at the bottom and the rest of the records in that field are Null. Then the SQL takes the due date, subtracts the duration (in days) from the record above it, and makes that the due date of that record. The problem is that it only does this once, and my table varies in length dependent on user input.

Comment: If I click cmd_7 a bunch of times it fills that same number of records.

Comment: Id have to agree - without knowing what buildCriteria does there's only so much we can do for you. However, all the wasted processing power in all the D Functions seems unnecessary. Even without knowing what BuildCriteria does, I am pretty certain you could handle this entire procedure with one SQL command

Comment: Is there a way to have it click the button for the number of records that exist? Running the SQL command once only fills one record, I need to fill the whole table.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.BuildCriteria @DougCoats

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what build criteria does, it helped me fix some formatting issues d=since duration is in number of days and due_date is in short date "d" format.

Comment: Oh that's a neat function ive never used before. Makes more sense now

Comment: Thanks @Andre - that's a new one for me too - I've updated my answer above.

Comment: @Lee MAC, yes, this code is essentially forcing access to work like excel. There's too much data to work with pivot tables in Excel, it's way easier in Access...but this one portion would've been much better in excel. I'll give that code a shot, thanks!

Comment: I'm confused on how to integrate the code, I've had it running off a button click, and the code begins with a Sub, how do I run it?

Comment: Yes, it's a very useful function to let the user enter (kinda) natural language filter expressions and create SQL filters from them. The devil is in the details, though. @DougCoats and Lee.

Comment: @cm2115 I've updated my answer and have changed the name of the `Sub` to match your existing example. Simply replace the code for your existing example with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider actually no `For` loop, no `BuildCriteria` and even no VBA SQL. Save the update query as an MS Access action query object that is run on button click.

Specifically, you would need several domain functions --`DLookUp`, `DSum`, and `DMax`-- where you calculate a running sum of duration days (i.e., a correlated aggregate computation) and then `DateAdd` the result to the *DueDate* of the corresponding maximum `ID` with no missing *DueDate*.

**SQL**

```sql
UPDATE myTable d
SET d.DueDate =  DateAdd("d", -1 * DSum("Duration", "DueDateDuration", "ID >= " & d.ID),  
                                         DLookUp("DueDate", "DueDateDuration", "ID = " &  
                                                 DMax("ID", "DueDateDuration", "DueDate IS NOT NULL") 
                                       )
                        )
WHERE d.DueDate IS NULL;
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub Command7_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedUpdateQuery"     ' WITH WARNINGS

    CurrentDb.Execute "mySavedUpdateQuery"   ' WITHOUT WARNINGS
End Sub
```

---

To demonstrate on sample data:

**Before Update** *(mytable)*

```
ID      Item       Duration     DueDate
2674    Issue             1   2/18/2019
2675    Shipping          1   2/19/2019
2678    Completed         0   2/20/2019
2679    Issue             1 
2680    Shipping         10 
2681    Other             6 
2682    Buy Off           6 
2683    Punch List        3 
2684    Completed         0   3/29/2019
```

**After Update** *(mytable)*

```
ID      Item       Duration     DueDate
2674    Issue             1   2/18/2019
2675    Shipping          1   2/19/2019
2678    Completed         0   2/20/2019
2679    Issue             1    3/3/2019
2680    Shipping         10    3/4/2019
2681    Other             6   3/14/2019
2682    Buy Off           6   3/20/2019
2683    Punch List        3   3/26/2019
2684    Completed         0   3/29/2019
```

Comment: Hello all. Any chance we can get my original code to work? I'm going to have to add a few more variables amd make it more complex, so being able to write sql with my variables would be a huge help.